# « Social engineering » : « piratage » et/ou « fraude » ou autrement ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, informatique, comparaison-de-langues

Comme équivalent de *social engineering*, le Grand dictionnaire terminologique (OQLF) donne « [piratage/fraude psychologique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8349717) » et déconseille le calque *ingénierie sociale* qui ne rendrait pas adéquatement compte de l'idée de « tromperie » qui serait propre au concept (« Tromperie qui résulte d'échanges entre individus afin d'extorquer des informations dans le but de pénétrer frauduleusement un système. », [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8349717)).

- Peut-on imaginer des contextes où l'un des choix (*piratage/fraude*)
  apparaîtrait meilleur que l'autre et pourquoi ?
- Pourquoi serait-on d'accord – ou pas – avec l'idée que le terme
  *ingénierie (sociale)* ne rend pas adéquatement compte de ce dont il est question en français ; l’équivalence peut-elle être à géométrie variable selon le [domaine](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17019208) ?

Comment: Possiblement OT. Je reconnais que je n'ai vu ce terme (anglais) que très récemment et, avant même que de savoir ce qu'il signifiait l'ai pris en mauvaise part. Possiblement à cause de deux raisons : A/ Je connaissais le *reverse ingeneering* qui n'a jamais guère été autre chose que du piratage 2/ L'incongruité qui consiste à faire de l'ingénierie avec de l'humain.

Comment: Les ordinateurs sont tellement présents dans notre vie quotidienne que je n’aurais pas jugé utile d’y faire une allusion même minime dans la traduction. J’aurais simplement parlé d’_abus de confiance_.

Comment: @aCOSwt Il n'y a pas à proprement parler d'incongruité; il existe une petite science appelé à l'origine « human engineering » que l'on appelle aussi « human factors psychology » ou « engineering psychology »  et  à laquelle on tend à référer de nos jours tout simplement en tant que « ergonomics ». Il n'est pas question de faire de l'ingénierie avec de l'humain mais d'adapter la technologie à l'humain. Comme dans beaucoup de formation de composés il n'existe pas dans celle-ci de rapport évident entre les éléments.

Comment: Ancien français transmis au monde juridique : ***dol*** https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol — pour une fois que le français s’écrit avec moins de lettre …

Comment: "Je connaissais le reverse ingeneering qui n'a jamais guère été autre chose que du piratage" Ceci est parfaitement faux. En tant qu'ingénieur je fais régulièrement du reverse engineering et ce n'est en rien du piratage. C'est faire des expériences de comportement sur un système dont on ne connaît pas le fonctionnement interne justement pour déduire son fonctionnement interne et pouvoir le fabriquer à nouveau (utile par exemple en informatique si l'on a perdu le code source d'un logiciel).

Answer (score 2):

> Pourquoi serait-on d'accord où pas avec l'idée que le terme ingénierie
>   (sociale) ne rend pas adéquatement compte de ce dont il est question
>   en français ; l'équivalence peut-elle être à géométrie variable selon
>   le domaine ?

Tout simplement parce qu'il n'existe pas de verbe "ingénierer" en français et qu'ingénierie ne se rapporte pas au sens suivant d'*[engineer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/engineer)* :

*2a : to contrive or plan out usually with more or less subtle skill
and craft*

L'expression "ingénierie sociale" est donc peu significative pour un francophone.

> Peut-on imaginer des contextes où l'un des choix (piratage/fraude)
>   apparaîtrait meilleur que l'autre et pourquoi ?

Je préfère pour ma part "fraude psychologique" : comme le remarque justement aCOSwt dans son commentaire, il parait incongru de pirater un humain. Par ailleurs, il n'y a pas besoin d'être un pirate au sens d'un technicien pour pratiquer le *social engineering*, c'est d'ailleurs ce qui en fait la simplicité et l'efficacité.

Answer (score 1):

En France, j'aurai plutôt utilisé la définition proposée par l'ANSSI ([ingénierie sociale](https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/entreprise/glossaire/i/)). Toutefois, le terme « détournement informatique » est aussi valable. En soi, ces dénominations expriment des nuances ou divers sens voire des connotations. Sinon, on trouve aussi ce genre de constructions avec des termes comme guerre électronique ou guerre psychologique, lesquels peuvent aussi sembler étranges. Avec du recul, le terme d'ingénierie sociale me semble plus global parce que l'on évoque un scénario (quelque chose de plannifié ou de préétabli, plus ou moins évident) et pas seulement le moyen (faire preuve de psychologie) ou la conséquence (fraude ou piratage).

Answer (score 0):

C'est une question assez large, et qui implique dans une certaine mesure l'opinion des locuteurs selon leurs habitudes et leur domaine d'activité, mais je vais tenter de répondre avec mon point de vue.

***Peut-on imaginer des contextes où l'un des choix (piratage/fraude) apparaîtrait meilleur que l'autre et pourquoi ?***

Pour ma part, je pense que la réponse à cette question dépend du sujet d'attention principal dans le contexte. Revenons à la base des termes proposés.

- **Piratage :**

D'après [la définition du dictionnaire Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pirater/61127), le verbe "pirater" possède 3 sens différents, dont deux nous intéressent particulièrement dans ce contexte :

> Voler, dérober quelque chose **à quelqu'un** : *Il m'a piraté mes idées*.
>
> Accéder illégalement à un système informatique depuis **un ordinateur distant** afin d'en consulter les données, de les modifier, voire de les **subtiliser**.

Dans les deux cas, une notion revient : lorsque l'on pirate, on pirate quelque chose ou quelqu'un, on implique une tierce entité. Le sujet central dans le cadre d'un piratage, **c'est la victime**.

- **Fraude :**

Prenons encore une fois [la définition du dictionnaire Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fraude/35120?q=fraude#35093):

> Acte malhonnête fait dans l'intention de tromper en contrevenant à la loi ou aux règlements.

Ici, on ne s'empare pas nécessairement du bien d'autrui. On réalise un acte malveillant pour soi (et pas forcément pour nuire aux autres). Le sujet central de la fraude, **c'est le fraudeur**.

Si on applique à présent ce raisonnement au contexte du *social engineering*, ma réponse est la suivante :

- Si l'acte malveillant est réalisé dans le but de nuire à une entité en particulier, c'est un piratage psychologique.
- Si l'acte malveillant est réalisé dans le but de contourner la loi pour éviter certaines contraintes, c'est une fraude psychologique.

Cette réponse n'est ni parfaite, ni absolue. Parfois, il est difficile de trancher de façon aussi nette : un piratage peut également être une fraude, et vice-versa. Dans cette situation, on s'en remettra au contexte.

Pour étoffer mon point de vue, voici quelques exemples :

> *Le suspect aurait convaincu Madame Dupont de lui donner son numéro de carte bancaire, qu'il aurait ensuite revendu sur Internet.* -> **Piratage psychologique.**
>
> *En devenant ami avec l'administrateur du site Internet de déclaration des impôts, il a fait en sorte de diminuer son taux de prélèvement à la source.* -> **Fraude psychologique**
>
> *En convainquant Madame Dupont, agente fiscale, de lui donner son numéro de carte bancaire, il a pu lui faire du chantage par la suite afin qu'elle lui diminue son taux de prélèvement à la source.* -> **Piratage *et* fraude psychologique ?**

***Pourquoi serait-on d'accord – ou pas – avec l'idée que le terme ingénierie (sociale) ne rend pas adéquatement compte de ce dont il est question en français ; l’équivalence peut-elle être à géométrie variable selon le domaine ?***

C'est une question très ouverte. À titre personnel, je suis d'accord avec cette idée. Étant donné que le terme *social engineering* est surtout employé dans un contexte de sécurité de l'information, je trouve ambigü de parler d'ingénierie lorsqu'elle désigne déjà une activité totalement différente dans ce contexte.

Reprenons [la définition du dictionnaire Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ing%C3%A9nierie/43049?q=ing%C3%A9nierie#42952) pour le terme "ingénierie" :

> Étude d'un projet industriel sous tous ses aspects (techniques, économiques, financiers, monétaires et sociaux) et qui nécessite un travail de synthèse coordonnant les travaux de plusieurs équipes de spécialistes.

Pour simplifier, je définis l'ingénierie comme la conception et la gestion d'un projet industriel. Dans le domaine de l'informatique, l'ingénierie peut prendre de multiples formes : concevoir une infrastructure logicielle, gérer et documenter des projets de développement, étudier les questions de sécurité au sein d'une entreprise...

Selon moi, la notion de tromperie ne rentre jamais (par défaut) dans un cadre industriel, aussi élaborée soit la supercherie.

**Oui, mais...**

Comme je suis de bonne foi, voici un cas dans lequel à mon avis, il n'est pas déplacé d'employer le terme d'ingénierie psychologique : **l'escroquerie organisée / à grande échelle**.

Prenons le cas d'une entreprise (malhonnête), dont l'unique but est d'extorquer des informations à des personnes âgées pour les revendre ensuite sur Internet. Cette entreprise se compose de :

- Une équipe de hackers, qui code des virus qui seront injectés dans l'ordinateur des victimes.
- Une équipe de "commerciaux", qui prennent contact avec la victime, la mettent en confiance, et la convainquent d'utiliser une clé USB contenant le virus codé par l'équipe technique.
- Un "chef de projet", qui coordonne les opérations, propose des pistes techniques, gère le budget et la rémunération des personnes à son service.

Ici, on est dans un cadre quasi-industriel. Le "chef de projet" réalise un travail d'ingénieur (bien qu'il soit dommage d'utiliser ses compétences à de telles fins...) et dans ce cas, je serais tenté de désigner son activité comme une opération d'ingénierie sociale.

Pour conclure, ma réponse à cette deuxième question est donc : **l'équivalence serait plutôt à géométrie variable selon l'échelle, et non le domaine lui-même**.

Answer (score -2):

J'ai une aversion certaine pour cette formulation du concept de fraude visé mais pas exactement selon les critères de l'OQLF. Il me semble qu'il importe peut qu'elle puisse être un calque de l'anglais, pourvu que ce soit le calque d'une formulation valable, et cela n'est apparemment pas le cas. Ce terme, « social engineering » est un terme tout comme « emotional engineering », qui est apparu le siècle dernier pour identifier un nouveau champ de connaissances dans le domaines des sciences sociales, ce qui est confirmé dans la dernière référence de la question (voir aussi par exemple [ceci](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FJ7KAAAAMAAJ&q=%22social+engineering%22&dq=%22social+engineering%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLyd3G2eHlAhVORBoKHQlkBroQ6AEInwEwDg). L'usage récent qui a été fait de « social engineering » pour nommer une activité frauduleuse est un détournement (aberrant, doit-on dire) de cette assignation première, laquelle reste quand même utilisée, comme on peut le vérifier d'après un certain nombre de sources ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Ep-lRoFJFY4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22social+engineering%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ4eru3OHlAhUPWBoKHffgDzoQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q=%22social%20engineering%22&f=false)). Voilà donc la raison première, selon mon point de vue, pour ne pas utiliser cette forme.

Je ne considère pas utile du tout d'imaginer des exemples dans lesquels « piratage » ou « fraude » pourrait convenir mieux ; le concept cerné par le terme « social engineering » selon l'acception première n'a pas le moindre rapport avec la notion de fraude et réfère à des processus totalement étrangers à ceux dont il est question et qui se limitent à des manipulations illégales au moyen de l'informatique ; en plus de cela il existe une énorme disproportion d'importance entre les concepts. Cela suffit pour trouver les deux autres termes comme étant les seuls des trois qui aient un intérêt.

Le terme « piratage psychologique » apparait comme étant un autre de ces terme qui ont prétention à expliquer une nouveauté et qui ne communiquent en fait rien que l'on ne sache déjà, mais de façon pompeuse, ici le simple fait d'une tromperie comme lorsque quelqu'un est escroqué après une discussion tissée de mensonge le menant à  signer un papier qui l'engage, manipulation qui n'est pas moins du piratage, pas moins une affaire de psychologie. Si l'on doit identifier cette sorte particulière de tromperie qui peut se faire par l'intermédiaire de l'internet, cela n'étant en aucun cas l'identification du processus de base que l'on trouve dans « piratage psychologique », un terme descriptif auto-défini comme « escroquerie par internet »  sera un terme bien plus convenable à défaut d'un terme plus court et à définir. De plus il n'y a dans « piratage psychologique » ni l'idée d'utilisation de l'internet ni celle de pénétration d'un système  et on ne se soucie pas d'exprimer des idée similaires par le terme « escroquerie » de toute façon, la généralité suffit et on est toujours à temps de mentionner quel type parmi le grand nombre de possibilités qui existent.