# Comment traduire « ... to social attacks they receive » : cohérence ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, ellipse

> Research points to users being significantly more susceptible to
>   social attacks they receive on mobile devices. [...] (*[2019 Data Breach Investigations Report](https://enterprise.verizon.com/resources/reports/2019-data-breach-investigations-report.pdf)*, Verizon Business, p. 14)

À la lecture du document je crois comprendre que *social [attack](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attack#English)s* vaut pour *social (engineering) [attack](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attack#English)s*.

Comment traduire *social attacks* (voir [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40285/19187) en guise d'introduction) : s'agit-il d'*attaques*, de *fraude* ou de *piratage* ; *attaque* fait-il double emploi avec un terme dans le choix de traduction de *social engineering* ou autrement quelle préposition/formulation choisit-on afin de lier le tout ; l'adjectif « social » est-il utile ; doit-on imiter l'ellipse de *engineering* : *attaque psychologique* fonctionne-t-il ?

Un exemple de tentative de traduction :

> Les recherches laissent présager d'une susceptibilité
>   significativement plus grande des utilisateurs à/aux [X] visant
>   leurs appareils mobiles.

Comment: Allez sur https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security) et choisissez à gauche la version française : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ing%C3%A9nierie_sociale_(s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9_de_l%27information) pour un début de réponse.

Comment: @MathieuBouville La question liée s'intéresse davantage au vocabulaire, selon la réponse qu'on y donne on traduira différemment, puis ici on ajoute la formulation avec le complément du nom et ce qui en résulte.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "X" would be, but I interpret the English as meaning "are more likely to fall for [X]s **received on** their mobile devices" and not "[coming] from" those devices, so couldn't "[Xs] **visant** (or "**reçues sur**") leur appareils mobiles" be closer than  "provenant de"?

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks, you're right, that's off, the translation part was quickly put together to showcase effort rather than accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Selon moi "social attacks" fait clairement référence au "social ingeneering" qui regroupe tous les types de manipulation visant un être humain (par opposition à une machine) afin de le conduire à faire ou dévoiler quelque chose qu'il ne devrait pas.

La traduction dépend de votre audience. Ce document est technique. Si le lecteur est averti, alors vous pouvez traduire "social attacks" par "ingénierie sociale". Sinon, je simplifierais simplement par "manipulation", "manipulation psychologique" ou "tentative de manipulation".

Exemple : « Les recherches montrent que les utilisateurs sont plus facilement victimes des tentatives de manipulations reçues via leurs appareils mobiles »

Attention à ne pas traduire par "visant leurs appareils mobiles" car, par exemple, un mail de phishing (la très grosse majorité de ces attaques) ne vise pas un appareil en particulier. D'ailleurs, par définition, l'ingénierie sociale vise l'humain et non la machine. Pour cela elle peut utiliser parfois des applications qui sont propres aux appareils mobiles mais ce n'est pas ici le sens de la phrase.